# Dynamic router link changes *slash* to %2F

Tags: vue.js, vue-router

I've got little problem with dynamic router link. I got array of objects(pages) from API, and one of them is my `home`:

```
{
    name:"dynamic"
    parent_id:0
    partners:null
    slug:"/"
}
```

then using `v-for` I want create `router-link` like this:

```
<div v-for="page in pages">
    <router-link
      :to="{ name: page.name, params: { slug: page.slug }}"
      class="v-list__link"
    >
</div>
```

Problem is when I render page this link to `home` is not `<a href="/">` as I expected but it is with endocing reference: `%2F` => `<a href="%2F">`

`router.js`

```
export default new Router({
  scrollBehavior (to, from) {
    return { x: 0, y: 0 }
  },
  mode: 'history',
  routes: [
    {
      path: '/:slug',
      name: 'dynamic',
      component: Dynamic
    },
    {
      path: '/',
      name: 'dynamic',
      component: Dynamic
    },
    {
      path: '/contact',
      name: 'contact',
      component: Contact
    }
  ]
})
```

does anyone know how to solve it ?

Comment: What is your router config routes?

Comment: @DecadeMoon I added router.js into topic

Comment: Not sure if it is related, but you have two routes with the same name (`dynamic`). Consider changing the one without the slug.

Comment: @Sumurai8 it must be like this, because when i go to www.test.com I don't have slug, and I'm using this slug for matching inside dynamic which component to lunch. So without slug i can't do it

Answer (score 0):

The route's path is `/:slug`. When resolved with `slug` equal to `/` then you get `//` as the final path, except it will be resolved to `/%2F` since the params will be encoded with [`encodeURIComponent`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/encodeURIComponent).

Remove the leading slash from the slug param:

```js
page.slug.replace(/^\//, '')
```

You also have two routes with the same name, this isn't allowed. The second `dynamic` route cannot be resolved by name.

Comment: hmm okay, but when I remove this second one at first enter page he cannot match which component to lunch. It works like this: I take whole response. Then I filter him using slug to take this current page, after this i check type of this page and inside dynamic component i'm matching which one to lunch.

Comment: Maybe try making the slug parameter optional like `/:slug?`.

Comment: okay it works, but now i have warn in console `missing param for named route "dynamic": Expected "slug" to match "[^\/]+?", but received ""`